# Move one Node to touch.location when already a few Nodes in scene with same name

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, sprite-kit, xcode8

I created a function that spawns a SKSpriteNode with name Ball and I created another function to animate it with 2 different colors. After they spawned I need to move one Ball to my touch.location, but when I create this it always takes the last spawned Node to move the location. So I just need to move one of a few balls that are currently in the scene and not the last one added.

Can someone please help me. Thanks in advance

```
    // Spawn forever

    let action = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.run(spawnRandomBall), SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1.2)])
    run(SKAction.repeatForever(action))


}



//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

func randomLocation (){

    let randomNumber = Int(arc4random() % 2)  // 0 and 1

    if randomNumber == 0 {

        roodball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 20, dy: 20))
        blauwball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 20, dy: 20))

    } else {

        roodball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: -20, dy: -20))
        blauwball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: -20, dy: -20))

    }


}

//.....................................................................................................//

func spawnRandomBall (){

    let randomNumber = Int(arc4random() % 2)  // 0 and 1

    if randomNumber == 0 {

        spawnRoodBall()

        } else {

        spawnBlauwBall()

        }



    roodball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: roodball.size.height / 2)
    roodball.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    roodball.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    roodball.physicsBody?.friction = 0
    roodball.physicsBody?.restitution = 1
    roodball.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
    roodball.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0
    roodball.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 1, dy: 1)


    blauwball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: blauwball.size.height / 2)
    blauwball.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    blauwball.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    blauwball.physicsBody?.friction = 0
    blauwball.physicsBody?.restitution = 1
    blauwball.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
    blauwball.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0
    blauwball.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 1, dy: 1)

    randomLocation()






}


//.....................................................................................................//

func spawnRoodBall () {

    roodball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "BalRood")
    roodball.position = CGPoint(x: 360, y: self.frame.midY - 38)
    roodball.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    roodball.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
    roodball.run(SKAction.animate(with: roodTextureArray, timePerFrame: 1.3))
    roodball.zPosition = 40






    let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 6.5)
    let remove = SKAction.removeFromParent()

    roodball.run(SKAction.sequence([wait, remove]), withKey: "waitRemove")



    self.addChild(roodball)

    }


//...................................................................................................//

func spawnBlauwBall () {

    blauwball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "BalBlauw")
    blauwball.position = CGPoint(x: 360, y: self.frame.midY - 38)
    blauwball.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    blauwball.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
    blauwball.run(SKAction.animate(with: blauwTextureArray, timePerFrame: 1.3))
    blauwball.zPosition = 40
    let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 6.5)
    let remove = SKAction.removeFromParent()

    blauwball.run(SKAction.sequence([wait, remove]), withKey: "waitRemove")



    self.addChild(blauwball)

    }
```

Comment: Please add code, nobody can help you without you providing your code

Comment: do not search by name, you need to search by touch point

Comment: edited my post.

Comment: Look into using the scene's subscript function (https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/sknode/1483070-subscript) to get an array of all the balls in the scene. Then pick one at random to move to the touch location via an `SKAction`.